# Pug accessing array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am developing a Node.js app with a SQL database returning an array of objects that are books and their details.

index.js route:

```
/* Books Section
_______________________________________________*/

/* GET books page. */
router.get('/books', function(req, res, next) {
  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM books';
  var query = db.query(sql, function (err, results) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  console.log(results);
  res.render('books', { title: 'Books', results });
 });
});
```

I am using `Pug` as a template engine like this:

```
extends layout

block content
    each book in books
        p #{this.BookName}
```

It gives this error message:

```
TypeError: D:\Semantik\website\mvp\views\books.pug:4
    2| 
    3| block content
  > 4|  each book in books
    5|      p #{this.BookName}

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `books` key to your object

```
res.render('books', { title: 'Books', books: results });
```

Your other option is to change your `each` statement so it looks like this

```
each book in results
```

Comment: Thank you mate :).. its been driving me nuts